# дано число и массив, найти два элемента массива сумма которых наиболее близка к числу

Tags: php

дано число и массив, найти два элемента массива сумма которых наиболее близка к числу r.

Я нашел только один элемент,как найти два?

```
$r=10;
$arr=[1,-1,2,9,9,-3,4,5,6,7,8,-9];

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
       if (abs($arr[$i]-$r)<abs($arr[0]-$r))$val=$arr[$i]; 
   }
echo $val;
```

Comment: И нашли вы неправильно. Точнее непонятно что вы нашли

Comment: Постройте двумерный массив и положите в него abs (сумма - число), потом найдите минимум. Таблицу можно строить виртуально

Comment: И ещё уточните, вам нужны все комбинации или можно первую попавшуюся?

Comment: @ArchDemon т.е. ? нужно найти два элемента массива сумма которых наиболее близка к числу r

Comment: 1 + 9 = 10, 2 + 8 = 10, 6 + 4 = 10. В ответе у вас должны быть все или только 1 комбинация

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное решение находит первую комбинацию чисел, подходящую условиям

```
<?php

$r=10;
$arr=[1,-1,2,9,9,-3,4,5,6,7,8,-9];

$min=abs($arr[0]+$arr[1]-$r);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
            $diff = abs($arr[$i]+$arr[$j]-$r);
            if ($diff < $min ) {    
                $min = $diff;
                $val1 = $arr[$i];
                $val2 = $arr[$j];
            }
        } 
    }

echo "val1 = $val1", ", val2 = $val2";
```

Comment: Ну он найдет "1" и "9", то есть $arr[0] и $arr[3]. Он проигнорит дальнейшие комбинации: "4" и "6", "2" и "8" и т.д. Хотя, судя по заданию, вам только одна комбинация и нужна.